# reversed index match - find value in Matrix and return matching value from Colum L

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

NO VBA OR MACROS allowed, it has to be able to run on an iPad / other tablet

I have a matrix of unique Serial numbers  (C2:K21)  (some cells are empty some contains numbers)
I have a list of all the numbers in the matrix (found via Array formula)  `(=INDIREKTE(TEKST(MIN(HVIS(($C$2:$K$100<>"")*(TÆL.HVIS($N$2:N3;$C$2:$K$100)=0);RÆKKE(C$2:K$100)*100+KOLONNE($C$2:$K$100);7^8));"R0C00");)&"")`

so in column P I have a list of Serial Numbers, what i would Really like is the value from Column L printed in Column Q

So it should take the value from P3 find it in the matrix C2:K2 and return value from column N from the same row.

Comment: Yes some are not Unique in this example - if this happens  the best option would be to return a list, but without VBA, i think this is semi imposible, next best return value from first match, third best... just dont breake the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Function**

Enter following function in cell Q3:

```
=OFFSET($L$1,SUM(1*(P3=$C$2:$K$21)*(ROW($B$2:$B$21)-ROW($B$1))),0,1,1)
```

Google sheet here (noting sheets don't handle this function for some reason, but perfectly valid in Microsoft Excel, I include a screenshot below as evidence)...

**Screenshot**

[image: Application within excel.]

Good luck with the rest of your project mate!

Comment: Thank you - "any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" - and this is how i feel about the offset  and strange multiplying of rows from a matrix. Also  in danish it would be=FORSKYDNING($L$1;SUM(1*(Q3=$C$2:$K$85)*(RÆKKE($B$2:$B$85)-RÆKKE($B$1)));0;1;1)

Comment: Cool - upvote if it helps, otherwise let me know if you were looking for an alternate solution/something else.